# Return all rows in a table that has specific column header text using Xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following HTML table in a page:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have the following Xpath:

```
//table[//th[contains(text(), "Birth Date")]]/tr
```

I get rows from all tables in the page, not the one with the `Birth Date` header.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am executing this Xpath in the Scrapy Web-scraping framework.

Comment: would bs4 be an acceptable alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want then I think you are close. I think you want

```
'//table[.//th[contains(text(), "Birth Date")]]//tr'
```

(note the `.` before `//th` to query with respect to the table rather than the entire document).

You could also write this as

```
'//table[contains(.//th/text(), "Birth Date")]//tr'
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason that you have *table based layout* on this page: you have one big main table, each cell contains another tables and so on.

You need to be more specific to find your target table:

```
//table[ tbody/tr/th[contains(text(), "Birth Date")] ]/tbody/tr
```